# How to draw molecular orbital diagrams for protonated/deprotonated methyl red?

Tags: organic-chemistry, spectroscopy, uv-vis-spectroscopy

> Give a molecular structure-based explanation for the differences in the UV-Vis
> spectra in **I** and **II**. Use detailed MO schemes for **A** and **B** for illustration. (12 marks)
>
> [image: Methyl red protonation]

Does the double bond of N=N, C=O and lone pair of oxygen and nitrogen involved in the MO diagram?

Comment: The longer the conjugated pi-system, the longer the absorbed wavelength. In the form A, there is a huge conjugated pi system . It is probably II. In the form B, there are two separate conjugated pi system. it corresponds probably to I.

Comment: I am able to assign A and B to the their specta, however I am not sure on how to draw detailed MO schemes for A and B in order to show the electron transitions.